# PID implementation in arduino

Tags: c, arduino, pid-controller

I came across some code online in which the PID is implemented for arduino. I am confused of the implementation. I have basic understanding of how PID works, however my source of confusion is why the hexadecimal is being used for m_prevError? what is the value 0x80000000L representing and why is right shifting by 10 when calculating the velocity?

```
// ServoLoop Constructor
ServoLoop::ServoLoop(int32_t proportionalGain, int32_t derivativeGain)
{
    m_pos = RCS_CENTER_POS;
    m_proportionalGain = proportionalGain;
    m_derivativeGain = derivativeGain;
    m_prevError = 0x80000000L;
}

// ServoLoop Update 
// Calculates new output based on the measured
// error and the current state.
void ServoLoop::update(int32_t error)
{
    long int velocity;
    char buf[32];
    if (m_prevError!=0x80000000)
    {   
        velocity = (error*m_proportionalGain + (error - m_prevError)*m_derivativeGain)>>10;

        m_pos += velocity;
        if (m_pos>RCS_MAX_POS) 
        {
            m_pos = RCS_MAX_POS; 
        }
        else if (m_pos<RCS_MIN_POS) 
        {
            m_pos = RCS_MIN_POS;
        }
    }
    m_prevError = error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shifting a binary number to right by 1 means multiplying its corresponding decimal value by 2. Here shifting by 10 means multiplying by 2^10 which is 1024. As any basic control loop, it could be a gain of the velocity where the returned-back value is converted to be suitable to re-use by any other method.

The `L` here `0x80000000L` is declaring that value as `long`. So, this value `0x80000000` may be an initial value of error or so. Also, you need to revise the full program to see how things work and what value is assigned to something like `error`.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the other answer, shifting to the right has the effect to divide by a power of two, in this case `>> 10` would divide by 1024. But a real division would be better, more clear, and optimized by the compiler with a shift anyway. So I find this shift ugly.

The intent is to implement some float math without actually use floating point numbers - it is a kind of fixed point calculation, where the fractional part is about 10 bits. To understand, assuming to simplify the derivative coefficient=0, an m_proportionalGain set to 1024 would mean 1, while if set to 512 it would mean 0.5. In fact in the case of proportional=1024, and error=100, the formula would give

```
100*1024 / 1024 = 100
```

(gain=1), while proportional=512 would give

```
100*512 / 1024 = 50
```

(gain=0.5).

As for previous error `m_prevError` set to 0x80000000, it is simply a special value which is checked in the loop to see if "there is already" a previous error. If not, i.e. if prevError has the special value, the entire loop is skipped once; in other words, it serves the purpose to skip the first update after creation of the object. Not very cleaver I suppose, I would prefer to simply set the previous error equal to 0 and skip completely the check in ::update(). Using special values as flag has the problem that sometimes the calculations result in the special value itself - it would be a big bug. If absolutely needed, it is better to use a true flag.

All in all, I think this is a poor PID algorithm, as it lacks completely the integrative part; it seems that the variable `m_pos` is thought for this integrative purpose, it is managed quite that way, but never used - only set. Nevertheless this algorithm can work, but all depends on the target system and the wanted performances: on most situations, this algorithm leaves a residual error.